# RTC on an mcu - function pointers and callbacks

Tags: c, pointers, callback, function-pointers, microcontroller

The code below is an example of how to use the real time clock on an mcu.

My question is in relation to callbacks and function pointers.

I have included the struct declaration for `rtc_config_t` below.

My question is, on the line `cfg.callback = rtc_example_callback`

1. Why is the `&` sign not used before rtc_example_callback.
2. Why is not necessary to pass the arguments to `rtc_example_callback`?
3. The last struct memeber `void *callback_data;` is set to `NULL`,  I don't understand what this does?
   When or what would you want to return?

Many tanks for your inputs

```
#include "rtc.h"
#include "interrupt.h"
#include "isr.h"

#define ALARM (QM_RTC_ALARM_MINUTE / 6)
#define MAX_RTC_FIRINGS (5)

void rtc_example_callback(void *);

static volatile uint32_t rtc_fired = 0;

/*  RTC app example */
int main(void)
{
    /*  Variables */
    rtc_config_t cfg; //create a struct variable to configure the RTC

    PRINTF("Starting: RTC\n");

    /*  Initialise RTC configuration */
    cfg.init_val = 0;
    cfg.alarm_en = true;
    cfg.alarm_val = ALARM;
    cfg.callback = rtc_example_callback;
    cfg.callback_data = NULL;

    irq_request(IRQ_RTC_0, rtc_isr_0); //submit the RTC to the interrupt service routine

    clk_periph_enable(CLK_PERIPH_RTC_REGISTER | CLK_PERIPH_CLK); //switch on RTC and Periphal clock

    rtc_set_config(RTC_0, &cfg); //Set the RTC configuration

    /* Wait for RTC to fire 5 times and then finish. */
    while (rtc_fired < MAX_RTC_FIRINGS) {
    }

    PRINTF("Finished: RTC\n");
    clk_periph_disable(CLK_PERIPH_RTC_REGISTER | CLK_PERIPH_CLK); //turn off the clocks
    return 0;
}

void rtc_example_callback(void *data)
{
    PUTS("Alarm!!\n");
    qm_rtc_set_alarm(RTC_0, (RTC[RTC_0].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));
    rtc_fired++;
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * RTC configuration type.
 */
typedef struct {
    uint32_t init_val;  /**< Initial value in RTC clocks. */
    bool alarm_en;      /**< Alarm enable. */
    uint32_t alarm_val; /**< Alarm value in RTC clocks. */

    /**
     * User callback.
     *
     * @param[in] data User defined data.
     */
    void (*callback)(void *data);
    void *callback_data; /**< Callback user data. */
} rtc_config_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. name of the function is a pointer to the function
2. function will be called with arguments from rtc library, you are not invoking it (you cannot pass arguments here).
3. I guess that NULL assigned to custom_callback will not call custom method from library (default function or no function will be called), just assign NULL if you dont want to use custom callback.

usually library code looks like:

```
if(custom_callback)
{
    custom_callback(some_parameters);
}
else
{
    default_callback(some_parameters);
}
```

Comment: You got the first two right.  But it's `callback_data` not `custom_callback` that's being set to NULL.  This simply means that a NULL pointer will be passed to the callback function when it is called from the RTC library.